# Switching flash scenes within a MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

How do I switch scenes within a flash MovieClip object with Flash CS5 and ActionScript 3?

Comment: Don't use scenes, they are buggy as hell!

Comment: Once you start jumping back and forth between scenes it'll just randomly stop working. I don't know why, but I always have my students avoid them like the plague, and once in a while someone does it anyway and it infallibly causes the strangest bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Dani,

First of all, coding within MovieClip objects in AS3 is not recommended AND using scenes are not recommended.

Why?

- Coding within MovieClip objects can be tempting if you are a beginner and this is alright.
  But if you are serious about the reusability of your assets and your code, you may want to dissociate your visual from your logic.
  *I'm suggesting you write your logic*

  - From the main timeline
  - From external classes (and using OOP)<sup>*This is great!*</sup>
- Scenes are bad because of the timeline and code issues.
  If some of your code is in a scene, it may be not accessible to the other scenes.

Enough talking, here's the help you need.

**How do I switch scenes within a Flash MovieClip object**

*This code is intended to be in a MovieClip frame*

```
// === Let's put the stage in a variable (cleaner) ===
var main:MovieClip = this.parent as MovieClip;
// this.parent will return the DisplayObject of parent the current clip.
// You need to cast [... as MovieClip] to not cause errors because Flash
// thinks it is only a DisplayObject

// === Here's the interresting part ===
main.gotoAndPlay(0, "Scene 2");
// We tell the main timeline to go to frame 0 in the "Scene 2"
// Be cautious, it must be spelled exactly as displayed in Flash (IDE)
```

Don't forget: Deeper is your clip (Embeded multiple times in a clip), more "parent" will you need.

```
var main:MovieClip = this.parent.parent as MovieClip;
// If your object is inside a MovieClip who is itself in a MovieClip
// Tip: How much time you need to push the Back button to go to the timeline
// is the number of parents you need to write.
```

Hoping this help. If you have any questions, just comment this answer!